# Div's Margin does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin, fixed

For some reason the margin of my content area, 150px top isn't working in internet explorer so that the content is going underneath the header. any help? I know generally fixed is a bit weird in internet explorer, but weirdly this seems to be working, it's just the content is starting off at the top of the page rather than 150px down.

```
    html {
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: auto;
}

body {
background-color: #FBFBFB;
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
}
#header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%; 
height: 150px;
background-color: #FBFBFB;
z-index: 100;
}

#sidebar {
position: fixed;
top: 150px;
left: 0;
width: 275px;
height: 100%;
z-index: 100;
}



#content {
width: 837px;
margin-top: 150px;
margin-left: 325px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML you're using as well, so we know where these elements are being placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a link that we can check?

Try "padding-top: 150px" instead, that mostly works unless there is something preventing you from doing that. Otherwise, try the regular tricks with "zoom: 1", "display: block", "position: relative" if they are applicable.

Comment: the padding trick worked, thankyou! so simple, yet so easy to miss.